# How to direct to another web page after clicking tabPanel in Shiny App

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have the following **[Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/)** app:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("X-men",
               tabPanel("",icon = icon("home", lib = "glyphicon")  ),
               tabPanel("Plot")
            )),
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
)
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It produces:

[image]

As stated there. How can I direct the page to www.google.com after clicking Home button `tabPanel()`?

---

**Update**

After using Phi's `html centric way` latest method:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**A UI-only solution**

There's no need to use reactive logic to redirect. We just want to put a link in the html.

---

Sometimes shiny lets you forget that what you're really doing is just writing html on the ui.

For example, if we print the output of `navbarPage` to the console we get:

```
> navbarPage("X-men",
+            tabPanel("",icon = icon("home", lib = "glyphicon")  ),
+            tabPanel("Plot")
+ )
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <span class="navbar-brand">X-men</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-8961-1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="">
          <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>

        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-8961-2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Plot">Plot</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" data-value="" data-icon-class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" id="tab-8961-1"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Plot" id="tab-8961-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue here is that the function `navbarPage` is applying some logic, it assumes that you only put tabPanel objects up there and it is doing something very special with the objects (it's creating a link in that spot, so any link we put inside that will get nullified). We can change that in one of two ways.

**1) Write HTML using the `tag` and/or `tags` objects and make your own function**

The first is simply to rewrite the `navbarPage` function in a way that produces the kind of output you're after.

You can look up the html for making a bootstrap navbar page and replicate it using `?tags` or `?tag`

(This is a great way to add new functionality to shiny. I wrote a package to speed this process by turning an html string into equivalent shiny functions: https://github.com/shapenaji/midas). But for something like this, that's overkill.

**2) Hack in the desired object to the output of the function.**

Here, we really just want to replace that home object in the header with a link, so lets just do that.

We save the output of the navbar function.

Then we replace that part of the object with our desired hack ...err... link.

A shiny object, like the output of `navbarPage` is just a list, and we can navigate our way to the bottom in the same way we would navigate a list.

(In this one, we have to dig a little bit to get down to the object. It's fairly deep in the nested list. But you can explore the object in the console to replace the parts you're after. I just peeled the list one at a time.)

(I have removed the shinyUI and shinyServer functions, as those wrappers are no longer necessary in the current version of shiny)

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = {
      page <- 
        navbarPage("X-men",id = "navibar",
                   tabPanel("placeholder"),
                   tabPanel("Plot",value = "plot"),
                   selected = "plot"
        )
      # Replace the second object in the navbar with the link
      page[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]] <- 
        tags$li(tags$a(
          href = 'http://google.com', 
          icon("home", lib = "glyphicon")
          )
        )
      # Finally return the page object, modified
      page
  },

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # No server code necessary (yet...)
  }
)
```

---

**How can I modify when `navbarPage()` is wrapped under `fixedPage()`**

Answer: Change what you're modifying, the entire navbar page is inside the fixed page now, which adds `page[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]]` to the beginning

```
page[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]][[3]][[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]] <- 
      tags$li(
        tags$a(
          href = 'http://google.com', 
          icon("home", lib = "glyphicon")
        )
      )
```

**EDIT 2: A Cleaner way to do it:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = {
      page <- 
        navbarPage("X-men",id = "navibar",
                   tabPanel("placeholder"),
                   tabPanel("Plot",value = "plot"),
                   selected = "plot"
        )
      # Replace the second object in the navbar with the link
      page[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]] <- 
        tags$li(tags$a(
          href = 'http://google.com', 
          icon("home", lib = "glyphicon")
          )
        )
      # Finally return the page object, wrapped by fixedPage
      fixedPage(page)
  },

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # No server code necessary (yet...)
  }
)
```

Comment: How can I modify your code if the `navbarPage` is wrapped under `fixedPage` See my update edit on your post.

Comment: Is the fixed page Necessary? If so, then the link is in a slightly different place. Though honestly I would just write your own function at that point. Bootstrap navpages are quite simple. But let me update for the fixed page at least

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate that. My original app was in `fixedPage()` I simplify the code for simplification.

Comment: `tabPanel("placeholder"),` this is not necessary right?

Comment: @neversaint well, technically no. You could do it by adding it between the first and second elements. but it's easier to replace a location in a list that already exists than to add it inside a list between two elements.

Comment: @neversaint also, if you are embedding this inside an existing app, you can also just put a `uiOutput` inside the fixed page. And then create a second `renderUI` to pass the entire navbar in, completely self-contained.

Comment: Can you give example for your last comment with `uiOutput insides the fixed page` ?

Comment: @neversaint While that's possible, I just realized, you can just stick the page inside the `fixedPage` when you return it, see edit

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can accomplish this in R and Shiny. Here's one :

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
shinyUI(
uiOutput("navigate")
),

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$navigate <- renderUI({
  fixedPage(
    navbarPage("X-men",id = "navibar",
               tabPanel("",icon = icon("home", lib = "glyphicon"),value = "home"),
               tabPanel("Plot",value = "plot"),
               selected = "plot"
    )
  )
})
observeEvent(input$navibar,{
  if(input$navibar == "home"){
    browseURL("https://www.google.com")
  }
})
})
)
```

Basically all thats happening is that the `observeEvent()` function is triggered when the tab is clicked on opening a browser window to the URL.Here's also an example of using ui.R and server.R rather than a single file.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
fluidPage(
navbarPage("X-men",id = "navibar",
                         tabPanel("",icon = icon("home", lib =  "glyphicon"),value = "home"),
                         tabPanel("Plot",value = "plot"),
                         selected = "plot"
)
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$navibar,{
if(input$navibar == "home"){
  browseURL("https://www.google.com")
}
})
})
```

Indeed we can also do this in a more html centric way, as Shape suggested, with a much simpler :

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
ui <- shinyUI(
navbarPage("X-men",
           tabPanel(tags$a(href = 'http://google.com', icon("home", lib = "glyphicon"))),
           tabPanel("Plot")
        )),
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with me. Why? I copy pasted your whole code.

Comment: I had a few errors in the copied code, its now edited to work correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the navbarPage in ui.R? logically it makes more sense. And I have a large navbarPage.

Comment: yes, just take the `navbarPage()` portion and put it in your ui.R and the `observeEvent()` portion into server.R.

Comment: can you please give example code? In my earlier comment I meant  navbarPage in either  `ui.R` or `shinyUI()`. The latter being in one file app.

Comment: Hard to read. It'll be really helpful if you can put it as edit in your post. Besides in your comment there I can't see the `shinyUI()`

Comment: Doing it with your HTML centric way would be best of all solutions. But I get distortion of the navbar. See my update. Is there a way to fix that?